# IF, invalid syntax error

Tags: syntax, python-3.4

```
if volt.isalpha() or res.isalpha() or amp.isalpha():
```

What did I do wrong here? I get an INVALID SYNTAX, I am using this for a calculator program I am making. It calculates voltage, resistance, and amperage. But thats the easy part, I am just trying to make it fool proof. I have 3 variables in the code (volt, amp, res) that are inputted by the user. I just wanna make sure that they don't type in anything stupid. Like letters for e.g. ...

```
try:
    float(volt) >= 0 and float(res) >= 0 and float(amp) >= 0
    print("")
    print("You put a value for everything. You don't need the calculator.")
    allowed = 0

if volt.isalpha() or res.isalpha() or amp.isalpha():
    print("You typed in characters for one of the values, this calculator doesn't use letters.")
    allowed = 0

def find_voltage(a,b):  # V = I * R
    voltage = a * b
    return(voltage)`
```

Comment: Can you post the section of code this line occurs in?  Perhaps it is an indentation problem.

Comment: I am very new to this site, how would I do that? c:

Comment: Click on [edit], paste your code into your question, highlight it, and click the `{}` button on the toolbar to properly format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an `except` block after `try` - it is required. Do something like:

```
try:
    float(volt) >= 0 and float(res) >= 0 and float(amp) >= 0
    print("")
    print("You put a value for everything. You don't need the calculator.")
    allowed = 0
except ValueError:
    print("Oops, you messed up.")
```

Additionally, the line

```
float(volt) >= 0 and float(res) >= 0 and float(amp) >= 0
```

doesn't do anything. You'll need to assign it to a variable, then check the results of the variable - if True, do one thing, if False, do something else.

Comment: @SamHolmes make sure you see my edit above - the first line in your `try` block doesn't do anything.

Comment: `try:
    float(volt) >= 0 and float(res) >= 0 and float(amp) >= 0
    print("")
    print("You put a value for everything. You don't need the calculator.")
    allowed = 0
except ValueError:
    allowed = 1`

Comment: This site is hard to use :( But basically everything is the same, but I added the except part I added, and the code runs now thanks very much!

Comment: BTW, if you'd like to learn more about the site, read through the [help] and the [site tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).